# How much delta-v does a typical geostationary satellite carry?

Tags: artificial-satellite

I'm wondering - how much delta-v do typical geostationary satellites carry with them once they get into the orbit for things like orbital adjustment or movement to the graveyard orbit?

Comment: Probably more of a Space Exploration question.

Comment: "Delta-V" is shorthand for an expenditure of energy.   The energy required to change the satellite's kinetic energy ( $\frac{mv^2}{2}$ )  depends on the satellite's mass as well as the total stored energy in the propellant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Space.SE]

Comment: @CarlWitthoft no, delta-v really is meant to express the available amount of velocity change that a spacecraft is capable of, or a maneuver requires. It is a measure of *specific energy* which is energy divided by mass. It's a bit hand-waving because the mass changes as propellant is depleted, but it's a real thing in spaceflight.

Comment: @JanDoggen "because it belongs on" is never a close reason. If it's off-topic here then state that it's off-topic here. I agree that a good place is Space SE, but new users reading your comment can get the idea that if they think a question is better asked somewhere else, or they think it "belongs" somewhere else, then that in and of itself is a close reason, which it isn't.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Astronomy as defined in the help center; see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). However, it is a good candidate for asking in [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/). You can consider just deleting here and posting there instead, or wait for it to be closed and see if it gets migrated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a mountain of readily available information, of which the following is one example.  From   [GOES page](http://spaceflight101.com/goes-r/goes-r-spacecraft/)

### edit

There is more information there about the thrust produced, so I suspect you can calculate the total delta-kinetic energy available.

> A2100 has been used for over 40 missions and is available in different versions catered to specific mission needs in terms of
> dimensions and power availability with satellite mass varying between
> 2,000 and 6,740 Kilograms.
>
> Each GOES-R-class satellite is 6.1 by 5.6 by 3.9 meters in size and has a dry mass of 2,857 Kilograms. At liftoff, the satellite
> weighs 5,192 Kilograms, loaded with propellants to support a mission
> of at least 14 years.
> GOES-R, S, T, U launches with a propellant and pressurant load of
> 2,335 Kilograms with Mixed Oxides of Nitrogen and Hydrazine acting as
> main propellant components and Helium gas used for the pressurization
> of tanks.